# Edit build definition error message

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, build-process, build-definition

I get this error every time I try to edit a build definition under Visual Studio 2010. I would get the following message "There were 0 failures, 6 errors and 0 warnings loading custom activities and services." in an info dialog box, and the following in the Output window for "Build - Team Foundation"

```
Summary: There were 0 failures, 6 errors and 0 warnings loading custom activities and services.

Error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Scripting, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Error: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users\myUsername\AppData\Local\Temp\VSTFSBuild\26d7c1b8-85e5-45bf-ab92-1dbeaed4388a\Microsoft.Scripting.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Error: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users\myUsername\AppData\Local\Temp\VSTFSBuild\26d7c1b8-85e5-45bf-ab92-1dbeaed4388a\Microsoft.Scripting.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Administration, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=9.0.242.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Error: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users\myUsername\AppData\Local\Temp\VSTFSBuild\26d7c1b8-85e5-45bf-ab92-1dbeaed4388a\Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

How do I prevent these error messages from showing every time I edit a build definition?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What exactly is your question? (I don't see a single phrase that qualifies as one, and I don't see a question mark anywhere either.) Are you asking something? Please edit your question to actually ask something (and provide some context), or it will probably be closed pretty quickly. You also might want to take a few minutes to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), particularly the section on how to ask a question. Thanks. :)

Comment: DO your build process templates use custom activities? Do those activities use these assemblies? Then you have to make sure the build servers know where these assemblies are located.

Comment: I'm using the DefaultTemplate.xml and I'm not using any custom activities.

Answer (score 1):

Is your located build-agent on a different physical machine? If yes (I suppose it): It's common to create a central team-project containing all possible dependencies which will not be installed or reachable on the build-server. Then you can use the option "Version control path to custom assemblies" in the build-controller-definition in the TFS Admin to get access to a TFS-folder containing those elements.